# Merge and transpose data from 2 arrays to create a new structure with header data as the first row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, transpose

> I wanna combine data array and series array to another dataset like source array,
> in Laravel,
> to draw charts, data is the axis, series are the item contents,
> I wanna reassemble these data so that they fit the data type of ECharts
> https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Dataset, the ref is here,
> can you show how to convert it,thanks

```
data: ['Matcha Latte', 'Milk Tea', 'Cheese Cocoa', 'Walnut Brownie']


series: [
            {
                name: '2015',
                data: [89.3, 92.1, 94.4, 85.4]
            },
            {

                name: '2016',
                data: [95.8, 89.4, 91.2, 76.9]
            },
            {

                name: '2017',
                data: [97.7, 83.1, 92.5, 78.1]
            }
          ]

<!-- result -->
source: [
            ['name', '2015', '2016', '2017'],
            ['Mha Latte', 89.3, 95.8, 97.7],
            ['Milk Tea', 92.1, 89.4, 83.1],
            ['Cheese Cocoa', 94.4, 91.2, 92.5],
            ['Walnut Brownie', 85.4, 76.9, 78.1]
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$data = ['Matcha Latte', 'Milk Tea', 'Cheese Cocoa', 'Walnut Brownie'];
$series = [
    [
        'name' => '2015',
        'data' => [89.3, 92.1, 94.4, 85.4]
    ],
    [
        'name' => '2016',
        'data' => [95.8, 89.4, 91.2, 76.9]
    ],
    [
        'name' => '2017',
        'data' => [97.7, 83.1, 92.5, 78.1]
    ],
];

$first = array_merge(['name'], array_map(function ($a) {
    return $a['name'];
}, $series));

$other = array_map(function ($a, $index) use ($series) {
    return array_merge([$a], array_map(function ($b) use ($index) {
        return $b['data'][$index];
    }, $series));
}, $data, array_keys($data));

$result = array_merge([$first], $other);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Isolate the `data` column from `$series`.
2. Transpose the `data` column array along with the `$data` array.
3. Prepend a row to that result of step #2 which contains the static word `name` then the year values from the `name` column of `$series`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3KrRe))

```
$result = array_map(null, $data, ...array_column($series, 'data'));  // non-header data
array_unshift($result, array_merge(['name'], array_column($series, 'name'))); // header data

var_export($result);
```